# My spam command doesn't work when the message has spaces

Tags: python, discord.py, error-code

my message is (Hello World!)

and command (/spam Hello World)

And the terminal : (sorry i can't copy paste it because the my terminal can not copy this)

[image: error code (sorry i can't copy paste it because the my terminal can not copy this)]

my code :

```
    @commands.command(description="you want spam but you slow typing? use this command")
async def spam(self, ctx, messages, amount : int):
  limit = 30
  print(f'bot spam amount : "{amount}" msg : "{message}"')
  if amount > limit:
    await ctx.send('spam count exceeded the limit (30)')
    print('not spamming')
  else:
    print('spamming')
    for _ in range(amount):
      await ctx.send(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your argument variable is `messages`, but you're printing out `message`: they need to be the same name. Secondly, it would be more ideal if your command took the `amount` before the `message`. How you would run this is `/spam 5 Hello World`, and it'll print out `Hello World` 5 times. To print out multiple words, just use `*` as an argument before the variable that will take in the multiple-word string. Try this out:

```py
@commands.command(description="you want spam but you slow typing? use this command")
async def spam(self, ctx, amount : int, *, message):
  limit = 30
  print(f'bot spam amount : "{amount}" msg : "{message}"')
  if amount > limit:
    await ctx.send('spam count exceeded the limit (30)')
    print('not spamming')
  else:
    print('spamming')
    for _ in range(amount):
      await ctx.send(message)
```